# Umbraco This document is published but its url would collide with content (error)

Tags: umbraco

I am new to Umbraco CMS. I have every thing setup but get the following error. (Highlighted in red.)

How do I set the URLs in Umbraco. Or fix them?

[image]

Comment: I have seen this in two different cases.  In a multi-site setup where you have not configured hostnames, or when using a Virtual Nodes plugin in Umbraco. Or either of these true for you?

Answer (score 0):

The alias (short URL) of a page is defined by the **name** that you give the page in the input bar at the top of the page:

[image: Name]

If you have two pages both named `Weddings`, then they will conflict; you can only access one view when visiting `/weddings/`.

In order to correct this, simply come up with unique names for your pages, such as `Indoor Weddings` and `Outdoor Weddings` (for example).

While these page names are mostly for organisation within the Umbraco CMS, they **will** be reflected in in URL, so I would recommend choosing something semantic.

Note that you can also set the page's URL manually with the **[UmbracoUrlName](https://our.umbraco.com/Documentation/Reference/Routing/routing-properties#umbracourlname)** (and **[UmbracoUrlAlias](https://our.umbraco.com/Documentation/Reference/Routing/routing-properties#umbracourlalias)**) routing property if need be.